# returnとはなにを返しているのか？

Tags: python, tkinter

プログラム1.

```
def make_cmd(i):
  return lambda : buff.set("button{} pressed".format(i))

button = Tkinter.Button(root, text = "Button{}".format(i), command = make_cmd(i))
```

プログラム2.

```
def make_cmd(i):
  return buff.set("button{} pressed".format(i))

button = Tkinter.Button(root, text = "Button{}".format(i), command = make_cmd(i))
```

1 の場合はうまく動作するのですが、2 は `button` への代入でエラーが出てしまいます。
1 の返り値を表示すると `<function <lambda> at 0xb714adbc>`、2 は `none` でした。
なぜ、2 は `none` になるのですか?

Comment: 一目で、`buff`の定義はどこでしょうか。あと、エラーって、`NameError`のエラーだったのでしょうか。

Comment: `f(x)` と一緒なのは `(lambda : f(x))()` なのです．

Comment: 「代入でエラーが出てしまいます」とありますが、どんなエラーでしたか？また、`buff` はどこで定義されていてどんな型ですか？それと、2 の場合の値は `none` ではなく `None` ではありませんでしたか？

Answer (score 3):

> なぜ、2 は none になるのですか?

buff.set()関数がNoneを返しているからです。

このプログラムでポイントになるのは、TKinter.Buttonのcommand引数へ渡す値です。
command引数は関数オブジェクトを期待しています。
例えばいかのような実装サンプルは正常に動作します。

```
def callback():
    print "click!"

b = Button(master, text="OK", command=callback)
```

ここで、プログラム1の実装を見てみると、lambdaを使っています。

```
def make_cmd(i):
    return lambda : buff.set("button{} pressed".format(i))
```

これをlambdaを使わずに実装すると、以下のようになります。

```
def make_cmd(i):
    def cmd():
        buff.set("button{} pressed".format(i))
    return cmd
```

`make_cmd` 関数が返しているのはcmd関数で、それがTKinter.Buttonのcommand引数に渡されることになります。 `buff.set` の返値をcommand引数に渡しているのではないことに注意して下さい。
この例ではcmdという関数内関数を定義していますが、これを短くインラインで書いたものがプログラム1にある `lambda` を使う方法です。lambdaを使えば、make_cmd関数を定義せずにTKinter.Buttonに直接渡す事もできます。

```
button = Tkinter.Button(
             root,
             text="Button{}".format(i),
             command=lambda:buff.set("button{} pressed".format(i))
         )
```

Answer (score 2):

とても簡単に言ってしまいますと、次のようになります。

プログラム1は、ラムダ式そのもの、つまりボタンが押されたときの処理関数を返しています。関数の内容はこの時点では実行されるわけではありません。ボタンが押されたときに実行されます。

プログラム2は、`buf.set()`の実行結果を返す形になっていますが、実際には何も返らないので、`none`になるのです。`buf.set()`はこの時点で実行されています。